# Iterating over a list then parsing in JSON: lexical error?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some parsing of the steam API. First I build a list of user IDs from a given steam group:

```
groupdata <- xmlParse("http://steamcommunity.com/groups/dogeLAN/memberslistxml?xml=1")

uids <- xmlToDataFrame(
  getNodeSet(groupdata, "//steamID64"),
  colClasses=c("character")
  )
```

I want to iterate over the user IDs and parse the data into a collected data frame:

```
gamedata_final <- data.frame(NULL)
for(i in uids){

  gamedata <- fromJSON(paste("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=[key removed for security]&steamid=",i,"&format=json&include_played_free_games=1", sep=""))

  gamedata_df <- data.frame(gamedata)
  gamedata_df$UID <- c("76561197988364229")
  gamedata_df$response.game_count <- NULL

  gamedata_final <- rbind(gamedata_df, gamedata_final)

}
```

The paste() function prints out the URLs that I want, which do work when run individually (outside the loop):

```
paste("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=&steamid=",i,"&format=json&include_played_free_games=1", sep="")
[1] "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=&steamid=76561197988364229&format=json&include_played_free_games=1"
 [2] "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=&steamid=76561197990340675&format=json&include_played_free_games=1"
 [3] "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=&steamid=76561197985004130&format=json&include_played_free_games=1"
```

Yet when I try to run the loop, I get an error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   http://api.steampowered.com/IPl
                 (right here) ------^
```

I feel like I'm approaching the pasting with the JSON parsing wrong, but I'm not sure where, exactly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the content from the url.
Try it with using getURL() from the RCurl library:

```
gamedata <- fromJSON(getURL(paste("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=[key removed for security]&steamid=",i,"&format=json&include_played_free_games=1", sep="")))
```